# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

*

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzb;

*
DESCRIPTION:-
During Debug it works fine however when trying to generate apk Android studio error above Error.

Comment: did you enable multi dex support in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of the different version of gradle for any of the google service module that you might be using in your project.

Check your Build.gradle file and the versions, they must be same.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of was the problem for me.
I did a
`./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile` and looked for what didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

It fix this error by reducing version, From  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1 to com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0